# SQL - Get the data based on the number of fields

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here my data would be like

[image]

**Here circle 1 is my default.**
 
I want the data like,

1. If user belongs to only circle1 (that is circle id 1), then return his/circle as it is.
2. If user belongs to another circles, then remove circle 1 data from the list and return.

I want the data like the following, 
[image]

Comment: Don't post images but formatted text, use the editor's code-button to format it as blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as the below:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Tbl A
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM Tbl B
        WHERE
            B.PersonId = A.PersonId AND
            B.CircleID <> 1
    ) OR
    A.CircleID <> 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this return circle 1, if user has only circle1?

Comment: Great Thanks.Still I have doubt.
You are selecting from tbl two times. Here in my actual query, where you placed Tbl, here I having join query. So If i do like the above method, then I need to call join two times. Right? then will this yield bad performance.

Comment: @JeevaJsb I do not agree with you. Can you try query?

Comment: Sure. I will check.

Comment: @JeevaJsb Query is ok?

Comment: As per your query, the inner join satisfy the condition and return all the circle 1 persons and then based on the or condition it will return all the Non circle values. So I am getting like if user belongs to circle 1 and circle 2, circle 1 doesn't omitted and returned with circle2.

Comment: Sorry I am getting the answer. I have another field isactive field. For person 1, isactive is set 1 for both the circle. Can i get the values regardless of the isactive. I have tried but not getting.

Comment: Great Thanks. This is working. I have just slightly modified based on my condition.